# Deploy on a remote server war + conf (cargo?)

Tags: tomcat, deployment, cargo

I'm searching for something that can deploy on an application server (tomcat) a war and its relative context.xml file and/or a properties file for the application. 
The problem is that the properties file should be in classpath of the application context (in conf/Catalina/localhost).

To make this i've found the Cargo Maven Plugin that seems what I need, but how can I make the deployment of the conf files in a remote server?
I'm not sure that this is possible...

otherwise you know someother way to do this?
**write in short** i need somenthing to make *mvn goal:install -P production* and the project is installed in a remote server without do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. You just have to bundle both files in your WAR file. The [context.xml](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#context.xml_configuration) sits in `META-INF/context.xml` and the [properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291398/java-accessing-properties-file-inside-a-war) under `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: the problem is I need to have the properties file out of the war, so the better solution is to put it in the tomcat classpath...

Comment: You want to have it outside of the WAR to be able to change the values or what is the reason behind it?

Comment: yes because who manage the configuration don't want to recompile and redeploy when only the configuration change

Comment: You'd only have to copy the file once right? So you can either copy it manually or use the [Maven Wagon plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html) to upload it.