# Accessing properties file in a JSF application programmatically

Tags: jsf, internationalization, resources, properties-file

I am trying to access the i18n properties file I'm using in my JSF application in code. (The idea is to have a page that displays its keys and values as a table actually.)

The project is a maven project, and in the src/resources/localization folder, and deployed in the war file in WEB-INF\classes\localization\

```
java.util.Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
String path = "localization/stat_codes.properties";
InputStream foo = prop.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

But the variable foo turns out to be null whatever I set the path variable to, /WEB-INF/classes/localization/stat_codes.properties, "localization.stat_codes.properties" etc. A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291398/java-accessing-properties-file-inside-a-war), but there is no helpful answer there as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `Class#getResourceAsStream()` can take a path which is relative to the location of the `Class` which you're using there as starting point. So, for example, if the class is located in the `com.example` package and you request the path `foo/filename.properties`, then it will *actually* load the `com/example/foo/filename.properties` file. But if you use `/foo/filename.properties`, then it will *actually* load `foo/filename.properties` from the classpath root.

So, your code

```
java.util.Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
String path = "localization/stat_codes.properties";
InputStream foo = prop.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

will *actually* look for `java/util/localization/stat_codes.properties` file.

But in applications with a complex multiple classloader hierarchy, the one classloader isn't the other. The classloader which loaded the core Java classes does not necessarily have knowledge about files which are in the webapp's `/WEB-INF/classes`. So prefixing the path with `/` will not necessarily be the solution, it would still return `null`.

If you can guarantee that the current class is visible by the same classloader as the properties files (because they're in the same sub-root of the classpath, e.g. `/WEB-INF/classes`, then you should indeed use

```
String path = "/localization/stat_codes.properties";
InputStream foo = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

But if at some point, the properties files will be externalized because of more easy maintenance/editing during runtime so that you don't need to rebuild/redeploy/restart the webapp whenever you want to edit the files, then the above line of code will likely fail as well. The externalized location would be only accessible by a different classloader. The canonical solution is to use the thread's context classloader as starting point instead, it has access to *all* resources in the classpath.

```
String path = "localization/stat_codes.properties";
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream foo = loader.getResourceAsStream(path);
```

*(note that this one cannot take a path starting with `/`, it's always relative to the common root)*

#### See also:

- [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app/)
- [ExternalContext#getResourceAsStream() returns null, where to place the resource file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784482/externalcontextgetresourceasstream-returns-null-where-to-place-the-resource)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the culprit is the `prop` object, I supposed any object would work, but it has to be the current object (`this`) on which the method `getClass()` is invoked, it seems. Also, the path should start with a `/` since the `localization` directory resides in `WEB-INF/classes`.

```
String path = "localization/stat_codes.properties";
InputStream foo = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
```