# Jasper Report in servelt generating a MalformedURLException

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports

I am writing a java servlet that should generate a jasper report. I have stored the jrxml under the WebContent folder in a folder named jrxml (WebContent/jrxml/theFile.jrxml). First I used the following code to generate the report:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("/jrxml/employeesList.jrxml"));
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
```

However, I kept getting a "No such file or directory" error message. So I then used the following code which I took from [Accessing properties file in a JSF application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952090/accessing-i18n-properties-file-in-a-jsf-application-programmatically/7955826#7955826) :

```
String path = "/jrxml/employeesList.jrxml";
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = loader.getResourceAsStream(path);
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
```

Now I no longer get a "No such file or directory" error message, but instead I get "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.net.MalformedURLException" exception, and according to the stack trace it is being cause by the fourth command (JRXmlLoader.load(input)). Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load a file in your WebContent folder you have to use [ServletContext.html#getRealPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) to get the actual path of the file in the filesystem, so you can try the following.

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/jrxml/employeesList.jrxml");
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
```

OTOH

If `ClassLoader` is used your resource should be in classpath (i.e. `WEB_INF\classes` or in any of the jars in `WEB-INF\lib`)

Answer (score -2):

Can you please try following..?

Specify full path such as..

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("F:/jrxml/employeesList.jrxml"));
```

Comment: This does not work, but the solution provided by Karthikeyan worked. Thanks anyway.