# How to set the classpath of properties file in Weblogic Admin Console?

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic

I am using Apache Tomcat Server.

While the application is loading it reads from a properties file and the file will be usuall placed in the lib folder of Tomcat server.

Since I am using Windows 7 and I need to test the application on **Weblogic Server 10.3.5**

While running the application it cannot deploy the application to the server because the server cannot find the properties file.

I tried giving the path of the properties file in

**Servers > AdminServer > Server Start > Class Path**

and tried to put the propertues file in the Weblogic Server HOME

**C:\ORA_WL\MIDDLEWARE\user_projects\domains\base_domain\lib**

But still it is giving the error

> java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.bonsai.webutility.properties.SystemProperties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does your class attempt to find the properties file? Using a relative path?

The `Server Start` tab only applies to servers started with the node manager, not with the `startWebLogic` script. So if your application is running on the admin server, you probably need to edit the `startWeblogic` script itself to put the properties file on your classpath.

A better option is to package the properties file directly in your .war/.ear. Reference the solution here: [Java: Accessing properties file inside a war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291398/java-accessing-properties-file-inside-a-war)

Comment: Yes, you are right after applying the Classpath `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\ORA-WL\MIDDLEWARE\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config\classpath` , it worked fine.