# Spring integration application failing on weblogic-properties file doesnt exist

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, weblogic

```
2018-01-02 15:55:27 DEBUG ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener:55 - Application failed to start with classpath: unknown
2018-01-02 15:55:27 ERROR SpringApplication:771 - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed  to parse configuration class [com.tsi.i
ntegration.starter.ApplicationBoot]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Application.
properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist at  org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181) at        org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(Configurat
ionClassPostProcessor.java:308)


 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Application.properties] cannot be opened because it does n
ot exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:154)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:72)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:58)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:65)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.DefaultPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(DefaultPropertySourceFactory.java:36)
```

Hi, I am loosing the exception format after the description.So, I put it first.  I am new to weblogic.I am trying to deploy a spring boot application -war file in weblogic. I am getting error as application.properties file doesnt exist. It was deployed successfully in embedded tomcontainer in sts. I found this [How to set the classpath of properties file in Weblogic Admin Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501220/how-to-set-the-classpath-of-properties-file-in-weblogic-admin-console). I dont have admin rights to change the classpath and it takes time. i dont have weblogicaux.jar or classes directory in my weblogic installation directory  as stated in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs/admindocs/classpath.html#weblogic_cp. Can someone help me to fix this

thanks for your help.